# Azure Website: Kudu fails to install

Tags: node.js, azure, ssl, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I started to run into this problem yesterday. Deploys fail when I run:

`npm install kudusync -g`

with the following error:

`Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED`

From some searches it appears that one of Kudu's dependencies is self-signed or unsigned. It seems like I can disable SSL checks for Node -- but that seems like a dangerous option and not recommended. Is anyone aware of any other workarounds?

The output in azure is as follows:

> remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kudusync[K
>   remote: ......[K
>
> remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kudusync[K
>   remote: .......................................................[K
>
> remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kudusync[K
>   remote: npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED[K
>
> remote: npm ERR!     at ClientRequest. (d:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:440:26)[K
>   remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.[K

Comment: You're probably using a really old version of NPM. From http://blog.npmjs.org/post/71267056460 - *If you are still using Node v0.6 for some reason, or a very old version of v0.8, you can work around this by doing npm config set strict-ssl false, though I’d really recommend that you upgrade, for this and many other reasons*

Comment: I don't seem to be able to specify a newer version via package.json, but it seems strange that this problem would start suddenly. I had no problem deploying before and have not made any changes to how I deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break most likely refers to [this change](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/71267056460/fastly-manta-loggly-and-couchdb-attachments) npm made.

Do you have a custom deployment script, or the standard script? With custom, your options are:

- use a newer version of npm
- run `npm config set strict-ssl false` before running npm
- if your custom script has a reference to `KUDU_SYNC_COMMAND`, rename that to `KUDU_SYNC_CMD`

Comment: The second option works but feels unsafe. The third option doesn't apply in my case. I wasn't able to see find a way to specify the NPM version in the Azure deployment script, is that possible?

Comment: The 3rd option will actually work for you. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/5357141 to see what I mean. Basically `KUDU_SYNC_CMD` gets passed in to you, such that you don't need to npm install kudusync at all. You can share your full script if that's not clear and I'll help clarify.